# Valueerror: DataFrame constructor not properly called while creating a pie chart of sales contribution by gender

Tags: plotly, data-analysis

I am trying to create a pie chart in plotly for showing the distribution of sales across males and females.
My code is

gender_sales = df.groupby('Gender')['gross income'].sum
fig = px.pie(gender_sales, values='gross income',names = 'Gender')

While executing, I'm getting the below error.

ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!

Please help.

I was expecting a pie chart.